# Why I don't see nodes on the map?

Tags: memgraphdb

I have a dataset that has longitude and latitude of subway stations. Here is an example what I get when I expand the results of `MATCH (n) RETURN n;` in Memgraph Lab.

```
{
   "id": 177,
   "labels": [
      "Station"
   ],
   "properties": {
      "latitude": 52.496161111,
      "longitude": 13.342702777,
      "name": "U-Bahnhof Viktoria-Luise-Platz"
   },
   "type": "node"
}
```

Query result - data:

[image: Query result - data]

I can see that Latitude and Longitude are defined for all nodes.

Graph schema:

[image: Graph schema]

I expected to get results shown on a map, not as a "circle" of nodes. How can I show my results on a map?

Graph results:

[image: Graph results]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memgraph Lab uses [Vislet](https://memgraph.com/blog/vislet-visualize-geographic-data-in-memgraph-lab) to show data on map layer. In order for this to there has to be `lat` and `lng` numeric properties. You need to rename `latitude` to `lat` and `longitude` to `lng`.

Here is cypher query that does that:

```
MATCH (n)
SET n.lat = n.latitude, n.lng = n.longitude
REMOVE n.latitude, n.longitude
```